# How can I resolve a $q.all in my controller in a Karma unit test?

Tags: angularjs, q, karma-jasmine

My controller has:

```
        switchUserAccount: function() {
            $scope.model.currentMode = 'user';
            console.log(ipCookie('currentPatientId'));
            $q.all([facilityCache.getFacility(), facilityGroupCache.getGroupList(), languageCache.getLanguageList(), genderCache.getGenderList(), raceCache.getRaceList(), dosingCache.getDosingOptions()])
                .then(function(){
                    console.log('back from then');
                    cache.set('ui', 'adminPage', '');
                    cache.set('ui', 'schedulePage', 'patients');
                    if(ipCookie('currentPatientId')) {
                        $location.path('/patient/view/' + ipCookie('currentPatientId'));
                    } else {
                        $location.path('/patients');
                    }
                });
        },
```

and my test is

```
describe('MainHeaderController', function() {
    var scope, $rootScope, $locationMock, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function() {
      module('mapApp');

      return inject(function($injector) {
        var $controller, $q, ipCookieMock;
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $q = $injector.get('$q');

        $locationMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$location', ['path'])
        ipCookieMock = function() {
            return 123;
        }

        scope = $rootScope.$new()

        $controller('MainHeaderController', {
            $scope: scope,
            $location: $locationMock,
            $q: $q,
            ipCookie: ipCookieMock
        });

        $httpBackend.whenGET('/rpc/session').respond(200);
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/rpc').respond(200);
        return scope.$digest();

      });
    });


    it('should redirect to a patient view if a cookie is set', function($rootScope) {
        scope.switchUserAccount();

        // $rootScope.$apply();
        expect($locationMock.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/patient/view/123');
    });

});
```

So what I expect to happen is for `$location.path` to be called with `/patient/view/123`. Instead, what I get is

```
Expected spy $location.path to have been called with [ '/patient/view/123' ] but actual calls were [  ].
```

If I uncomment out the `$rootScope.$apply()`, I get

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$rootScope.$apply()')
```

So how can I trigged the `$q.all` in my controller so that the test can pass properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hiding the `$rootScope` variable of your test suite by declaring it as an argument of your test function. That's why it's undefined: jasmine calls the test functions withput any argument.

Replace

```
it('should redirect to a patient view if a cookie is set', function($rootScope) {
```

by

```
it('should redirect to a patient view if a cookie is set', function() {
```